# Rasterize difference between QGIS and FWTools

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am wanting to use FWTools to rasterize a large number of Shapefile polygons.  I have used the Rasterize tool in QGIS and it works great.  But when I use the generated code in FWTools the process does not work.  Here is the generated code:

```
gdal_rasterize -a COVTYPE -ts 5000 3705 -l LCC001k_dis
C:/GlobalData/Vectors/LCC/LCCRasters/LCC001k_dis.shp
C:/GlobalData/Vectors/LCC/LCCRasters/LCC001k.tif
```

Unfortunately, I am not a programmer, so I am not able to create my own script to perform this task.  Can anyone assist me with why this code doesn't work in FWTools, or what changes I need to make to utilize the Rasterize functionality.

Comment: Do you get any errors or other output when running the code command?

Comment: No there is no error message.  It just brings up the usage.

Comment: It would be good to mark an answer to this and previous questions as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the answers.

Comment: FWTools uses an outdated gdal library, use binaries at gisinternals.com/sdk or QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my version of FWTools I don't think your command line would work either, it expects the raster to which you are burning the vectors to exist already. The version of gdal_rasterize that comes with recent versions of QGIS does not have this limitation, it can create the new raster. Nick.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  That was my suspicion, but I wanted to see if there was something I was missing.  Do you know of any other way I may be able to do this via a command line?  I want to batch the rasterization of hundreds of files.

Comment: If you're in Windows you could run gdal_rasterize from an OSGEO4W window. Or from any command line window, if you put in the path to the QGIS version of gdal_rasterize. Nick.

Comment: I just tried that with the same result:

C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.4.7>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\bin\gdal_rasterize.exe" gdal_rasterize -a COVTYPE -ts 5000 3705 -l LCC001k_dis C:/GlobalData/Vectors/LCC/LCCRasters/LCC001k_dis.shp C:/GlobalData/Vectors/LCC/LCCRasters/LCC001kz.tif

Comment: "...\bin\gdal_rasterize.exe" gdal_rasterize..." It looks as if you're calling gdal_rasterize twice :( Nick.

Comment: Thank you Nick, those second pair of eyes helped.  That was it. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanGarnett please upvote and accept the answer. that's how you can reward users who donate their time to help you.